# How can I reduce the amount of GLSL code written?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am writing a game engine for Linux. It has a sufficiently large number of effects that can be turned on / off. Effects are defined before compiling with `#ifdef`. But the problem is that I literally have to “wrap” each variable in `#ifdef`. Another problem is that when adding new effects, I have to rewrite the conditions, since one variable can refer to several effects at once. For example:

```
#if defined ALGINE_LIGHTING_MODE_ENABLED || defined ALGINE_SHADOW_MAPPING_MODE_ENABLED
uniform vec3 viewPos;                       // Camera position
#endif

#ifdef ALGINE_DOF_MODE_ENABLED
uniform float focalDepth;
uniform float focalRange;
#endif
```

How could I reduce the amount of re-write needed when adding new effects?

Comment: I don't think you need to conditionally disable uniforms. Any half-decent shader compiler will optimize them away if they're not used. *And* you don't have to conditionally disable writes to them: When using `glGetUniformLocation` with `glUniform*`, non-existing uniforms (including those that were optimized away) are silently ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using macros for defining the variables, then there is really no way around it. You could, however, do something like this:

```
// constants.h
#if defined ALGINE_LIGHTING_MODE_ENABLED || defined 
ALGINE_SHADOW_MAPPING_MODE_ENABLED
uniform vec3 viewPos;                       // Camera position
#endif

#ifdef ALGINE_DOF_MODE_ENABLED
uniform float focalDepth;
uniform float focalRange;
#endif
```

And then include this file in your shader code:

```
// vertex-shader.glsl
#include "constants.h"
// [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I decided to entrust the optimization of this code fragment to the compiler (as @HolyBlackCat advised), since I have a lot of these variables

Comment: Alright. If you do decide to use this though (or someone else does), then please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754437/how-to-using-the-include-in-glsl-support-arb-shading-language-include) for a description of how this can be achieved. Since glsl has no understanding of your file system, you will have to invent a small hack to manually load all the `#include`'d files together, and then do some string concatenation. But it is definitely possible.